# How to put each section with its tables separately?

Tags: floats, positioning, placeins

I have many sections and subsections and each section have many tables under it.

I am trying to make the tables positioned in the section that is using them, but everything is overlapped in the file.

I tried to put `\newpage` before each sections and subsections, but it did not work.

I tried to put:

```
\begin{table}[h]
....
\end{table}
```

also I tried:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
....
\end{table}
```

but all of these did not work.

What is the solution?

Comment: Tables are floats, so if there is not enough place in section, they will float out of it. Another problem can be that the ratio between text area and floats area is in one page is to small, than the floats are moved to the end of file. What you mean with "overlapped"? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Alternatively, you could use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`. The former, unlike the latter, will output any queued floats.

Never use `h` as the sole specifier for any float. It means

> Dear LaTeX,
>
> Please put this float right here, if there is room, and nowhere else.
>
> Yours,
>
> User

What is LaTeX to do if there *isn't* room? Adding `!` doesn't help at all.

Comment: Just a small wrinkle: LaTeX automatically converts `[h!]` to `[ht!]`. Hence, if the float really cannot be placed "right here", presumably because there isn't enough space left on the page, the float will be placed at the top of the next page -- and the remainder of the page will be filled with ordinary text. For sure, `[h!]` is much preferable to `[H]`, the "I want it HERE" specifier that's provided by the `float` package. The `H` specifier has the very unpleasant effect of creating a great big empty block on the remainder of the page if the float cannot be placed immediately.